# Convert multiple rows with multiple column into one record in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, transpose

In Oracle SQL query we got **40 records** having **13 columns**. I want to **merge** all these records into **one column** means **40 * 13 = 520** column in **1 record**. Eg- Sample table having few records

```
col1  col2  city  cntry  conti
1     abc   NYC   USA    NA
2     def   LON   UK     EU
3     xyz   DUB   UAE    ASIA
```

then after **merge** all the records & get into the one record then it should be like the below one-

```
col1  col2  city  cntry  conti  col1  col2  city  cntry  conti  col1  col2  city  cntry  conti  
1     abc   NYC   USA    NA     2     def   LON   UK     EU     3     xyz   DUB   UAE    ASIA
```

Comment: Oracle has a limit on the number of bytes in a single record.  You data may not fit on one row.

Comment: @GordonLinoff can you provide a reference to that limit? I [can find](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/refrn/logical-database-limits.html#GUID-685230CF-63F5-4C5A-B8B0-037C566BDA76) only the limitation of the columns per table.

Comment: "Maximum cumulative length of a row's fixed-length columns (bytes) = 32,768", https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/timesten.112/e21643/limit.htm#TTREF456.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If column `col1` contains unique values then you could use `pivot`:

```
select * 
  from t
  pivot (max(col1) col1, max(col2) col2, max(city) city, max(cntry), max(conti) conti 
         for col1 in (1, 2, 3))
```

**<sup>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/83b2cd/246)</sup>**

Comment: can we do with 40 * 13 = 420 column in 1 record

Comment: @PonderStibbons can above one execute on Oracle 10g because there is no any supported WITH clause in Oracle 10g. Without WITH clause is it possible to merge?

Comment: According to [this](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/with-clause) `WITH` clause was added in Oracle 9.2, but it's not so important here. `Pivot` was implemented in 11, so in 10 query has to be changed to `case when` (or `decode`) style - [here](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/pivot-and-unpivot-operators-11gr1) some examples.

Comment: @PonderStibbons code has been executed successfully but i didn't get any values of the columns after merging.